# Second derivative of convex decreasing functions larger than square of first derivative?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

Given a twice differentiable, convex, decreasing function $f\in C^2$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=k$, I am trying to identify some sufficient conditions for the second derivative to be larger than the square of the first derivative above some level $\bar x$, or
$$ f''(x) > f'(x)^2 \qquad x>\bar x.$$
I see that this is true of the negative exponential for $x>0$ and of the negative power function $1/x^n$ for $x^n>n/(n+1)$.

Comment: What if we impose that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f = k$, i.e. $f$ is asymptotically constant, this is more restrictive than $f'$ going to zero, isn't it?

Comment: However, this is not a decreasing function

Comment: Ok, I correct the question

Comment: You compare $f’’$ with $g(f’).$ But have you done the preliminary version where you compare $f’$ with $g(f(x) - k). ?$ I don’t know the answer to this- but I would want to investigate this first before I tried your question deeply.

Comment: It might or might not be easier to find a condition under which monotonically decreasing, positive sequences $a_n$ satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\lt \infty$ satisfy $a_n-a_{n+1} \gt a_n^2$, or $a_{n+1} \lt a_n(1-a_n)$. Here the $a_n$ would be the $f'(n)$.

Comment: Or maybe, you can construct the "smallest function with $f''(x)\le f'(x)^2$ with such-and-such derivative at $x_0$". Either way, you need to assume the second derivative is monotonic. Otherwise, you could initially define $f(x):=e^{-x}$, choose some infinite sequence of short intervals, a long way apart, then on each interval, set $f'(x)$ to be constant, and shift the function values of $f$ down appropriately.

Comment: Right, I change the question imposing the restriction that $f\in C^2$

Comment: As $(\ln f)''=\frac{f''f-f'^2}{f^2}$, the condition $f''>f'^2$ should be related to log-convexity of $f+C$ for a proper chosen constant $C$ (for large $x$ as $f\approx k$ there).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the easier claim, "Every convex, decreasing function $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ for which $f''(x)\le f'(x)^2$ satisfies $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x \to \infty$".

To prove this, let $g(x):=-f'(x)$, so the statement becomes "every decreasing, positive function $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ for which $g'(x)\ge -g(x)^2$ satisfies $\int_a^b g(x) \,dx \to \infty$ as $b \to \infty$. We only consider the case $g(x)\to 0$.

We argue that every function $g$ satisfying $g'(x)\ge -g(x)^2$ and $g(x_0)=y_0$ satisfies $g(x)\ge g_0(x)$ for all $x$, where $g_0$ is the function satisfying $g_0'(x)=-g(x)^2$ and $g_0(x_0)=y_0$. This follows since for every $0<y\le y_0$, we have $$g'(g^{-1}(y))\ge -y^2=g_0'(g_0^{-1}(y)).$$ That is, at any value $y$, $g$ cannot be decreasing faster than $g_0$ decreases at that $y$ value.

It is straightforward to check that if $g_0$ passes through $(x_0,y_0)$, then $g_0(x)=\frac{1}{x-x_0+y_0^{-1}}$, i.e. $f(x)=\int_a^x g_0(t)\,dt=\log(x-x_0+y_0^{-1})+c$, and thus the claim holds.

(As noted in the comments, you can't prove your statement without additional conditions. There is a counterexample given by initially taking $f(x):=e^{-x}$, then on each interval $(10^n,10^n+1)$, replace $f$ with a linear approximation. This gives $f''(x)=0$ and $f'(x)\ne 0$ at a sequence of points diverging to $\infty$).

Comment: Do you think my statement can be proved if we impose monotonicity/continuity on derivatives?

Comment: I suspect not. You could have a piecewise-exponential decay (with smoothing) where you suddenly decrease the second derivative after every time the first derivative is halved, or something.